# Export KML to SHP in Javascript

Tags: shapefile, javascript, kml, export

I need my Javascript browser application to convert/export KML documents into ESRI shapefiles. Is there any JS library that can do it? I tried googling, but no answers so far (at least, not in Javascript).

Comment: Why do you need to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[js2shapefile](http://code.google.com/p/js2shapefile/) looks like it should be able to do this, although it may require you to write or use a separate KML parser. See [this code](http://code.google.com/p/js2shapefile/source/browse/trunk/tests/Gmaps_Demo_JS2Shapefile.html) for example usage with Google Maps.

Comment: Thanks, this will definitely be useful! Any other option?

Comment: According to me No. @blah js2shapefile is the perfect fits for me thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

You can the this [link](http://geospatialearth.in/Point2Poly) too. Here CSV files are being converted to either KML or Shapefile using js2shapefile.

You can check the source code how it works. This is a working example.